# can t select a single row in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. i have been struggling since the morning to complete this form it is about a gridview where the owner can validate or revoke a request to borrow a book when he clicks "valider" the columns "Etat" in the database should take the value 2 instead of the initial value 1 then he should disappears from this gridview and get inserted in table "Emprunt".
2. when he clicks "annuler" the columns "Etat" should get the value 0 and disappear from the table "Reservation".
   asp.net:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Liste des réservation.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Liste_des_réservation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Width="629px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
                <%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id Adherant">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("IdAdherent") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdAdherent" Text='<%#Eval("IdAdherent") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
               <%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code Livre">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("CodeLivre") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="CodeLivre" Text='<%#Eval("CodeLivre") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
               <%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>
                 <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Résérvation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("dateRes") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="dateRes" Text='<%#Eval("dateRes") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
               <%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>

                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id Réservation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("IdReservation") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="IdReservation" Text='<%#Eval("IdReservation") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
               <%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Controls">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Valider" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Valider"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Annuler" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>                
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Liste_des_réservation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string cn = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-VMKKO27;Initial Catalog=Emprunter_livre;Integrated Security=True";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                chargerReservation();
            }
        }

        void chargerReservation()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cn))
            {
                cnx.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Reservation where Etat = 1", cnx);
                da.Fill(dt);
                cnx.Close();
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cn))
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    Label lb = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("IdReservation") as Label;
                    
                    
                        ////Label IdAdherent = (Label)row.FindControl("IdAdherent");
                        cnx.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Reservation set Etat =2 where IdReservation=@IdRes ", cnx);
                        //var a = GridView1.ow.FindControl("IdReservation");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdRes", lb);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cnx.Close();
                    
                   
                }

                }

        }
    }

}
```

Database query sql

```
create database Emprunter_Livre
go
use Emprunter_Livre
go
select * from Auteur
create table Auteur(
    IdAuteur int primary key identity,
    Nom varchar(20),
    Prenom varchar(20)

)
select * from Livre
create table Livre(
    CodeLivre int primary key identity,
    Titre varchar(35),
    Isbn varchar(12),
    Langue varchar(20),
    Disponibilité varchar(30),
    IdAuteur int foreign key references Auteur(IdAuteur)

)
create table Bibliothècaire(
    IdBibliothècaire int primary key identity,
    Nom varchar(20),
    Prenom varchar(20),
    Password varchar(50),
    DateInscription date default getdate()

)
create table Membre(
    IdAdherent int primary key identity,
    Nom varchar(20),
    Prenom varchar(20),
    Sexe char(1) check(Sexe in ('M','F')),
    DateNaiss date check(dateNaiss<getdate()),
    Email varchar(120),
    Password varchar(50),
    DateInscription date default getdate()

)

create table Reservation(
    IdReservation int primary key identity,
    IdAdherent int foreign key references Membre(IdAdherent),
    CodeLivre int foreign key references Livre(CodeLivre),
    Etat int check(Etat in(0,1,2)),
    dateRes date default getdate()

)
create table Emprunt(
    IdEmprunt int primary key identity,
    IdReservation int foreign key references Reservation(IdReservation),
    DateEmprunt date default getdate(),
    DateRendu date,
    IdBibliothècaireEmp int foreign key references Bibliothècaire(IdBibliothècaire),
    IdBibliothècaireRendu int foreign key references Bibliothècaire(IdBibliothècaire),

)
select * from Membre
select * from Livre
select * from Auteur
select * from Reservation
update Reservation set Etat = 1 where Idreservation=1
insert into Reservation values(2003,2009,1,default)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few things. You have this tagged as mvc, and it looks to be a webforms applcation. not a huge deal, and while webforms are somewhat "legacy" right now, they are still a fantastic way to get your feet wet in asp.net (but, do try and jump over to mvc say for your next project). And there are boatloads of legacy sites having been built around webforms - as a result, often you find just as much work - and often even more work in web forms as opposed to MVC projects.

Ok, next suggesting?

You don't have to bother what the "command" stuff, and trigger the row command. But VERY strange is how you have a row command, yet the code in your row command which should operate on ONE ROW looks to be looping over all rows in the grid? Why is this so? (perhaps a desperate attempt at making this work ? - in other words it would have been nice for you to have explained why you have that looping code in the row command?

However, while oh so many examples and code suggests to use the row command?

You REALLY do not need it and I would in fact 100% dump and remove the code you have in row command.

You are free to drop in a plane jane asp.net button into the grid view, and use a standard click event, and this lets you get the current row clicked on.

I see you using a LinkButton - and that will also work, but even a asp:Button can also be used. However, as noted, I STRONG suggest you dump the use of command to trigger the row command - don't bother.

Ok, so lets wire up a event for your button

we have:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdValidate" Text="Valider" runat="server" ToolTip="Valider"
  OnClick="cmdValidate_Click"
```

And really, once again, like all buttons, textbox and just about everything else?

Your buttons don't have a "id", and they should.

Next up, we need (and want) to define the PK row ID for each row, so in the GridView, we want to add this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" runat="server"
DataKeyNames="IdReservation"

bla bla bla
```

To be fair, I would in fact dump the edit template also - you dont need it, but we have to save that for another day and time and question.

So, now that we have a plane jane regular button click even for the above link button?

Then the code behind can look like this:

```
   protected void cmdValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        // ok, we have the grid view row.
        now, we update database
        int PKres = (int)GVHotels.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["IdReservation"];

   using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(cn))
        {
        cnx.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Reservation set Etat =2 where IdReservation = @IdRes ", cnx);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdRes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKres;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // re-load grid
        chargerReservation();
```

So, above code should get your update working. And probably to add to above, is your required insert statement you talked about that adds a row to some other table. but get the button click (linkbutton) code working first. And then add to above click event the code to insert the data into that other table.